# Input method removes transparent effect from JFrame in Swing

Tags: java, swing, ime

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TranslucentIssueTest extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        (new TranslucentIssueTest()).setVisible(true);
    }

    public TranslucentIssueTest()
    {
        super();
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(300, 300);
        AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false);

        JTextField box = new JTextField();
        box.setBounds(30, 150, 100, 25);
        add(box);
    }
}
```

The code above creates a textfield on transparent frame.

But when I typed some Chinese characters into the box using an input method, transparent effect was removed automatically. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't appear to anything major wrong.  I would suggest creating the UI within the event dispatching thread and use a layout manager though

Comment: @MadProgrammer well thx for your suggestions, but I don't think they're related to IME problems... Is it a known bug in swing?

Comment: Not known to me. (I didn't try the Chinese input though), but I had a little paint artifacts when using a null layout and not honoring the single thread requirements of Swing will always cause you issues, you just don't know when ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer +1. I tried flow layout, but still no luck...

Comment: @skies457 why not put a `setText` of some chinese in there so we can see what happens. i.e Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp It seems that IME cause the problem rather than Chinese characters. I also tried several different IME including one shipped with Windows 8, but none of them successfully interacted with swing.

Comment: @skies457 Have you tried setting the content pane to transparent, ((JComponent)getContentPane()).setOpaque(false) ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer No luck. Even overriding paintComponent() in content panel and clearing the background with (0, 0, 0, 0) has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into what appears to be the same issue and thought I'd post my solution for anyone who finds this question while searching. The problem seems to be due to a bug in the DirectDraw pipeline in Swing. I'm using an older version of Java 7 (update 5), so it's possible that this has been fixed in one of the later releases.

The problem doesn't seem to be with the IME specifically, but rather with the rendering calls that get made by the text field while the IME is active.

The simplest way to work around the problem is to just disable DirectDraw rendering by making the following call before any GUI code is run:

```java
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "true");
```

If you'd rather not disable DirectDraw rendering entirely, you can work around  the specific `JTextField` issue by overriding its `paintComponent` method to write to a buffer as in the example below.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    public static class JTextField2 extends JTextField {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private BufferedImage buffer = null;

        @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Component window = this.getTopLevelAncestor();
            if (window instanceof Window && !((Window)window).isOpaque()) {
                // This is a translucent window, so we need to draw to a buffer
                // first to work around a bug in the DirectDraw rendering in Swing.
                int w = this.getWidth();
                int h = this.getHeight();
                if (buffer == null || buffer.getWidth() != w || buffer.getHeight() != h) {
                    // Create a new buffer based on the current size.
                    GraphicsConfiguration gc = this.getGraphicsConfiguration();
                    buffer = gc.createCompatibleImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
                }

                // Use the super class's paintComponent implementation to draw to
                // the buffer, then write that buffer to the original Graphics object.
                Graphics bufferGraphics = buffer.createGraphics();
                try {
                    super.paintComponent(bufferGraphics);
                } finally {
                    bufferGraphics.dispose();
                }
                g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w, h, null);
            } else {
                // This is not a translucent window, so we can call the super class
                // implementation directly.
                super.paintComponent(g);
            }        
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(96, 128, 160, 192));

                JTextField textField = new JTextField2();                
                JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
                exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        frame.dispose();
                    }
                });

                frame.add(exitButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
                frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```